# VB.Net Threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am working on a process at the moment which iterates through files in a folder; its used as part of a data migration. Each iteration of a file takes about 8 seconds; I need to run it about 30000 times so 8s that is a bit of a problem. The actions in the function cant be multithreaded as it pulls apart the document and that needs to be serial.

The single threaded code does this

```
    For Each strFile In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPathIN.Text)
        CallFunction(strFile)
    Next
```

What is the best approach to convert this to make it multithreaded? There is no feedback to the user; just need to start the process and iterate through them as quickly as possible. What the easiest way to making this multithreaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx). Something like this:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads = 4

For Each strFile In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPathIN.Text)
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(addressof CallFunction), strFile)
Next
```

You could also use your own thread pooling system by having a list of threads and using a mutex to stop the main thread from exiting before all the child threads have finished running.

Comment: So Simple :) Was expecting something so much more complicated. Thanks :)

Comment: This is quite clever and one I would myself consider, but it introduces the problem of each thread processing the same file multiple times, unless you keep track of the files processed, which means thread-safe lists. Great idea though!

Comment: FYI I did a test and seems like ArrayList.Synchronized(your_list) will return a thread-safe array that should work between the threads, for keeping track of which files you have already processed.