# Send file in chunks using multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to send a file in chunks by calling a function that calls a webservice using multithreading.

The following is a brief of the code:

```
int chunkSize = "whatever in byte";
byte[] fileBytes = ConvFileToByte("the pathe of the file");
int numberOfParts = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)fileSize / chunkSize);
for (int i; i< numberOfParts; i++)
{
  //Get the offset.
  //Get the bytes to send.

  SendFile(ByteToSend, offset) // This call a method in a webservice.
}
```

What is the best way to use mutithreading in this function?

Note: but don't forget that if one chunk failed to send I should send it again.

Comment: Can you send them out of order? Do you need to send them using the same TCP/IP connection or can you send them as multiple connections?

Comment: What's the purpose of using multiple threads for this?  Sending a file is an I/O-bound task, not CPU-bound, so parallelizing the CPU work isn't likely to gain you anything.

Comment: i don't use TCP/IP i call a function in a web service

Comment: That's still using TCP/IP, just indirectly.  You're still limited by the available bandwidth for sending data to the web service.

Comment: Wyzard: i am not using multithreading for splitting the file or something like that i call a function in webservice.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question.  It sounds to me like you've split the file up into chunks, and now you want to have thread 1 send chunk A at the same time as thread 2 sends chunk B, etc.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. Can you send the chunks using multiple webservice calls? And still, can you send them out of order (for instance, could you send the last chunk first)

Comment: Wyzard: yes exactly thats what i am trying to do ... see the the code above now

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen :yes i want to send chunks in multiple webservice and  yes i could send the last chunk first

Comment: Ok, do you compete with other uploads either from the machine you're sending from (ie. you have torrent files going), or on the server you're uploading to (ie. it's a regular web server that people download files from.)

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen : its a regular web server

Comment: Ok, the reason I'm asking is that if you start sending 10 simultaneous uploads, and the web server incoming router divides the bandwidth equally between the competing requests, you're going to gain a larger share since you have multiple requests going at the same time. If you want to do that, follow the advice of @naivists to use the TreadPool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have multiple instances of your webservice under some kind of loadbalancing AND your upload bandwith is higher than the download capabilities of each single service host, it does not make sense to multithread your call if you want to achieve higher upload speeds.

On the other hand, if the file you want to upload is very large and you want to limit the amount of memory used to buffer the file, then chunking makes sense. If this is your case and if you have control over the webservice implementation, you should consider using [WCF chunking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx) instead of writing your own chunking mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If your web service is safe to receive the chunks out of order, consider using the `ThreadPool` class (see an excellent example here: [VB.Net Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019911/vb-net-threading)). You will be able to set the number of parallel threads etc.

Re-sending can be done inside the function that uploads a single chunk. Say, if the request fails (does not get the "200" response from server), you start over again (will have to count times you have retried, otherwise an ifinite loop is possible).